# Problem using \write18 in beamer frame

Tags: beamer, shell-escape

I am stuck in front of this little but annoying problem. I am trying to use a `\write18` command in which I use a local variable `\mytest`.
I really don't understand why this SWE works if I comment the two `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` and doesn't if I use them. Also, it works if I use `\jobname` in place of `\mytest` in the `\write18` statement.

Does anybody can has an idea ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\print}[1]{
  \def\mytest{#1}
  \mytest
  \write18{echo;echo my test is \mytest\   }
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\print{hello world}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\write18` is executed at shipout time, when the frame has already ended, so the local definition of `\mytest` has been discarded.

If you use `\immediate\write18` you get what you want. Of course, the instruction will be executed as many times as there are overlays in the frame, so perhaps an `\only` instruction should be used.